# How do I disable touchpad tap to click?

Tags: touchpad

You've heard this a million times but the "tap to click" is a pain in the behind and I want to disable it. There is no touchpad in gpointing-device-settings and neither in *mouse and touchpad* in system settings. I've tried some commands in terminal but it's all crap. Dconf-editor doesn't react. How about solving this once and for all?

Comp: Dell inspiron N5110

xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

EDIT:

I think someone fixed it [here on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238)

Can someone explain the fix like I was a four year old idiot? (using precise pangolin)

Comment: I have a little script that works for me and probably works for you. I will post it for you later today when I am home. ;)

Comment: what do you get when you run `xinput list'? Please paste it somewhere all the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/117010/how-to-disable-touchpad-tap-in-toshiba-tecra-r850-in-oneiric-it-is-recognized

Comment: Well it's multiplicate because there doesn't seem to be a solution for all.

Comment: Can you add the model laptop to your question? Perhaps we can narrow this down a bit.

Comment: I have the same issue with an `Asus X53S`, I just want to disable click on tap, while keeping the other features of the touchpad.

Comment: Same problem with a Dell Inspiron there: * http://askubuntu.com/questions/118892/how-do-i-disable-touchpad-tap-to-click
* http://askubuntu.com/questions/109345/no-touchpad-tab-under-mouse-and-touchpad-settings-detected-as-ps-2-generic-mo?rq=1 * http://askubuntu.com/questions/149258/dell-n5110-touch-pad-scroll-bar-not-recognized-in-ubuntu-12-0-4?rq=1

Comment: They're working on it: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238](http://) [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/144](http://) [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/147](http://)

Answer (score 28):

Type this into the terminal:

```
synclient MaxTapTime=0
```

But it will only work for the session, unfortunately.

I have also found [this](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/11/06/persistent-touchpad-configuration-in-ubuntu-11-10/) which I have now tried myself

Essentially it is a way to put the synclient settings MaxTapTime=0 into an executable file (I personally don't like fixes which involve installing GUIs on lubuntu - the whole point of it is lightness.

I have now found that there is a way to get a .sh file to come on at startup in lubuntu see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166777/how-can-you-make-a-sh-file-come-on-at-startup-in-lubuntu-12-04) thread where I asked about it.

If you type

```
>>synclient
```

Into terminal. This will bring up all the possible settings for the touchpad, so you can potentially do more tweaking.

Comment: I recommend further editing this answer to summarize the basic points of the link you've added.

Comment: [Can't one put the settings for the touchpad into xorg.conf or another common system configuration file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70428/4319)

Comment: Seems it is possible. I have not tried it myself but +1 for adding the link.

Comment: synclient results in:`Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

Comment: Make permanent by updating/creating `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-synaptics-options.conf ` as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/290009/how-do-i-make-my-synclient-settings-stick#293748

Answer (score 21):

All Settings--> Mouse and Touchpad --> uncheck "tap to click"

[image: Settings / Mouse & Touchpad / Tap to Click]

The image is from Ubuntu 16.04 as it appears on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460.

I disabled 'tap to click'. I use the touch pad buttons for clicking. This makes my life much better with Ubuntu and Mint.

Comment: Unfortunately not all setups have this option (as apparent in the 2nd sentence of the question).

Answer (score 2):

I just tried a the **Wayland** Gnome session on 17.04 and I noticed that it has many more touchpad options than the X11 session – including a persistent tap-to-click setting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my Ubuntu 12.04 (for Toshiba AC100), there is such an option in the settings, exactly as shown in the image in https://askubuntu.com/a/85069/19753 .

Perhaps, the required **component of the settings menu** isn't installed in your system. What can be the explanation otherwise?

Perhaps, that's [the problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/185443/19753) regarding "the **ALPS touchpads** which are not recognized by Ubuntu. They behave as a PS2 mouse and the touchpad tab is missing from the mouse menu. Therefore there is no scroll option and, the most annoying thing, while typing, the cursor often jumps because I touch the touchpad. I found a program which can disable the touchpad on command: `touchpad-indicator`, which was found on the Ubuntu help page. This program seems to be able to stop and start the touchpad on command."

I don't know whether you have such an ALPS touchpad. If so, `touchpad-indicator` could be of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

For KDE, set Touchpad settings → Tap Detection → Maximum Time to 0 ms. Verify by checking that the output of the command `synclient` contains `MaxTapTime = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered in the past, but I found for my 2017 xps, I needed to add a few additional settings to actually disable it. I think made the more modern synaptics drivers use these settings instead.

```
synclient TapButton1=0
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
```