# Swap drive not turning on when I log in

Tags: boot, permissions, lubuntu, swap

Recently I added a new 40GB hard drive as swap. I want the swap to be enabled when the computer logs me in. I followed the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166777/how-can-you-make-a-sh-file-come-on-at-startup-in-lubuntu-12-04) to make the swap command run on start up.

I added `swaps.desktop` to `/etc/xdg/autostart/` as well as to `/usr/share/applications/`. Inside `swaps.desktop` is this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Swap Drive Autostart
Exec=swapon -p 32767 /dev/sda5
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

I am sure that the command shown (`swapon -p 32767 /dev/sda5`) works on its own, but when I restarted the computer, the swap was not enabled.

Then I made the file supposedly able to be run as myself (using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password)) because the file was not being run at start up:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo chmod 700 /etc/xdg/autostart/

sudo chown root:root /usr/share/applications/
sudo chmod 700 /usr/share/applications/
```

I also did `sudo visudo` and added the lines:

```
administrator  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/xdg/autostart/swaps.desktop
administrator  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/share/applications/swaps.desktop
```

`whoami` says that I am `administrator`.

End result: When I try to run either `swaps.desktop` file on their own, I get `Error: Permission denied.` But when I run the file with "Open Current Folder as Root", it runs flawlessly and my swap space shows up in `cat /proc/swaps`.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I make this work correctly so that the swap is enabled whenever I log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the fstab entry in `/etc/fstab`

It needs to be mentioned with your UUID

Here is my example of fstab entry

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c44126db-1f07-4dfa-a836-e478fecdd8d0 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

This is my swap entry which was Automatically created and u need to enter the value as show here

If you need to know the UUID of your drive, run the command

```
#blkid /dev/yourdrive
```

Then you will get the value like this:

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="c44126db-1f07-4dfa-a836-e478fecdd8d0" TYPE="swap"
```

See how i have run it in my PC :

```
root@system99:/home/sysadmin# blkid /dev/sda5 
/dev/sda5: UUID="c44126db-1f07-4dfa-a836-e478fecdd8d0" TYPE="swap"
```